How to implement direct memory mapping between guest and host in VM?
I'm working on my process virtual machine that runs as a process of the host system. The goal is to emulate target ISA of the guest software and provide seamless environment for the guest to run.
I am planning to implement two schemes of memory image mapping:

Indirect - via translation table that associate each guest virtual address with specific host virtual address and std::allocator.
Direct - without the table and lookup overhead.

My idea was to allocate contiguous memory block using, for instance, calloc. Find address of the first instruction of guest data segment, determine difference between data segment and allocated block. Every guest address + difference = corresponding host address.
I'm not sure if it is a correct approach and if so can you please provide the effective and safe method of contiguous memory allocation?
EDIT:

Host: AMD64, Windows 11 >21H2;
Guest: ARM >v8, Windows 11 >21H2/Arbitrary Linux distro (later as a separate module implementing Linux specific features);

Two basic emulation techniques are direct/indirect interpretation (for profiling) and binary translation (for optimization).

Let's back up.  Are you talking about running an emulator, like QEMU?  Or are you literally talking about a virtual machine, under control of a hypervisor like Xen?  Because those are very different requirements.  For an emulator, there are many ways to share memory between ordinary processes, although they tend to be operating-system specific.

Given that the guest is a different architecture, it's probably the first.

Since you're on windows, VirtualAlloc a terabyte of memory with MEM_RESERVE and treat that as the base address for guest memory. If you want to run anything besides a hello world VM you will have to implement page tables anyway so I'm not sure why you think you can avoid it.

@Tim Roberts, It's the first.

So, on Windows you can use MapViewOfFile to create a segment shared between two processes.  On Linux, you can use mmap.
